# Footer not getting stretched 100%

Tags: css

i have a footer in html

```
<div id="footer">       
</div>
```

whose css properties are

```
#footer{
    height:500px;
    background-color:#d0c5a6;
    float:left;
    padding:15px 0;
    min-width:100%;
}
```

but my footer is not stretched through whole page abt 5px space is shown on left and 5px on right Why?

Comment: did you do **clear : both** ?

Comment: give `padding: 15px 5px`. could be because of parent element styles..

Comment: do you reset the browser css? maybe it is a paading/margin of html- or body-tag

Comment: add `body{margin:0;padding:0}` in your css file.

Comment: check the width if the div in which your footer div is

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pARTq/

Comment: Can you post html here

Comment: @acudars yeah added but not working

Comment: try this padding: 15px -5px

Comment: @Mr.Alien thanx dear it worked let me accept ur answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you set `margin: 0;` for the footer and / or `margin: 0; padding: 0;` for the body/html?

Comment: Use comments to ask a question. When you are sure of the answer post it.

Comment: @mohkhan there is one problem with that `You need 50 rep to comment globally`. And it's seems that answer is pretty good.

Comment: Well, you got it now :)